# How to disable onclick and scrollbar of listview inside gridView

Tags: android

I am using a ListView inside of a GridView but I want to disable the onClick handler of the ListView.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

check this answer [disable click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16099113/disable-click-event-on-android-listview-items)

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call [setClickable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setClickable%28boolean%29) like this:

```
setClickable(false)
```

on your ListView object to prevent it responding to click events.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can try to create your subclass of ArrayAdapter with the funcion AreAllItemsEnabled() andd return false.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding `android:clickable="false"` to your `ListView`.

Answer (score -1):

Try to type this in layout XML file:

```
   android:scrollbars="none"
```