# Disable Click Event on Android ListView Items

Tags: android, listview, clickable

I'm trying to disable multiple click events on listview, say after pressing first click some media gets played from webservice, while it gets played, other items need to be `clickable==false` , after media got played,other list items can be clickable.

What I'm trying is calling `setClickable(true)` and `setClickable(false)` on `ListView` Object.

Comment: Set setClickable(false) on ListView  during MediaPlayer is Playing and setClickable(true) when MediaPlayer is not playing

Comment: try setEnabled(false); for listview

Answer (score 71):

In your custom ArrayAdapter overide isEnabled method as following

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Sexy, best solution :), used this on a GroupHeader in my list!

Answer (score 36):

Make your own subclass of ArrayAdapter that has [AreAllItemsEnabled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#areAllItemsEnabled%28%29)() return false, and define [isEnabled(int position)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#isEnabled) to return false for a given item in your the ones you want to disable.

Comment: So far it is working for me to have some of the TextViews themselves marked disabled, and thus avoiding having to have an isEnabled(int position) method. But having the AreAllItemsEnabled() method present and returning false is necessary, thanks for that tip.

Answer (score 19):

Add this to the xml

```
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: Smart Solution : Only if you don't want the touch highlight to be seen. -- Thanks

Answer (score 3):

create Adapter for that list, and there override this method

```
public boolean isEnabled(int position);
```

then return `false` when you want to disable the click

Answer (score 2):

Manage Click event using flags.

While your media player is running set click to false by using this method.

```
setClickable(false);
```

When your media player is stop or not running or on complete set that flag to default value.

```
 setClickable(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

before onCreate:

```
private long mLastClickTimeListViewItem = 0;
```

To prevent multiple clicks on ListView Items

After onCreate inside the listener for listView,in my case the following:

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTimeListViewItem < 1000){
                return ;
            }
            mLastClickTimeListViewItem = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

            //Do your remaining code magic below...
            ....
            ....

         } // end of onItemClick method   
    }); // end of setOnItemClickListner
```

Answer (score 2):

the above said answers didn't worked for me, so I used `list.setEnabled(false)` Its worked for me

Comment: Long lists become unscrollable

Answer (score 2):

listView.getChildAt(position).setEnabled(false);

listView.getChildAt(position).setClickable(false);

Answer (score 1):

Or in simple way to un-register and register **OnItemClickListener** can be a better idea.

Answer (score -1):

If what you want is just to diable items being clickable and show the appropriate selector color just use the line

android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"

in you listview in the layout file(xml)